# Interpolation x-vector

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I'm using the `interp1` function to interpolate some points on this graph

[image]

My problem is that I want the new points to be equidistant. But in the `interp1` function the input arguments are the `x(before)` , `y(before)` and the `x(new)` which is the vertical coordinate and not the contour distance.

My question is if there is any other function which solves my problem? If not, does anyone know how can I transform the x-vector?

EDIT:

an example with my problem is here:

```
x=0:0.1:10;
y=x.^4;

xx=linspace(min(x),max(x),10);
yy=interp1(x,y,xx);

hold on;
plot(x,y);
plot(xx,yy);
plot(xx,yy,'ro');
hold off;
```

Comment: yes , that line represents a spur gear's foot and the points are the first step in creating the mesh.

Comment: If you have the equation of the curve I think this could be solved as a [Calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) problem. Numerically this can be solved as an equidistribution problem (see my answer [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21849/17671)) taking a mesh density of `rho(x) = sqrt(1+(u_x)^2)`, where `u_x` is the first derivative of your curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by reformulating your curve as a parametric function of [length along the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). What you want is for the final points (where you interpolate) to have equal length between them. It's possible to do this by approximating the 'true' curve as a piecewise linear curve that connects the original data points.

Say we have some data points in matrix `xy`, where each row is a point and the x/y coordinates are on columns 1/2:

```
% make some fake data
% triple exponential function has nonuniform spacing
x = linspace(.4, .8, 20)';
y = exp(exp(exp(x)));
x = (x - min(x)) ./ range(x);
y = (y-min(y)) ./ range(y);
xy = [x, y];
```

Find the length of each point along the curve, starting from 0 at the first point:

```
% distance of each point from previous point
% note that points need to be in order
ds = [0; sqrt(sum(diff(xy, 1, 1) .^ 2, 2))];

% integrate to find length along the curve
s = cumsum(ds);
```

Now, consider both `x` and `y` to be a function of `s`. Interpolate `x` and `y` at a set of equally spaced lengths along the curve:

```
% find a set of equally spaced lengths along the curve
si = linspace(s(1), s(end), 20)';

% interpolate x and y at these points
xyi = interp1(s, xy, si);
```

Verify that the solution works:

```
% distance between successive interpolated points
% they should all be equal
sqrt(sum(diff(xyi, 1, 1) .^ 2, 2)
```

**Original data:**

[image]

**Interpolated:**

[image]